# Recovering data from an OLD ipod

Tags: ios, itunes, ipod-touch, ipod

I have recently dug up an old 2nd or 3rd generation iPod touch, from my childhood, which is running iOS 4. There are a few audio files on it I'd be interested in recovering, but cannot figure out how. It powers on fine, and can be connected to the computer (it starts charging), but neither the PC nor iTunes recognizes it as a device.

Any ideas?

Comment: Wondering if your version of iTunes might be too old. I would zip your current iTunes library folder (as a backup) and install an older version of iTunes https://support.apple.com/downloads/itunes. That *MIGHT* do the trick. But as it is an old unused device it just might be toast.

Comment: You might want to try the app [iExplorer](https://macroplant.com/iexplorer), which can open iDevices’ file systems. It has a free trial mode which you can use to see if it’ll work for you. Disclaimer: satisfied customer - no financial or other connection to Macroplant LLC.